# DotNet Templating: How to exclude directories without duplication?

Tags: templates, .net-core

In my template.json I have:

```
  "sources": [
    {
      "modifiers": [
        {
          "exclude": [
            ".idea/**",
            ".vscode/**",
            ".vs/**",
            ".DS_Store/**",
            "**/.idea/**",
            "**/.vscode/**",
            "**/.vs/**",
            "**/.DS_Store/**"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Is there a way I can exclude directories/folders having a name at any level?

Comment: If there a reason you are using `modifiers` instead of having the `exclude` directly under `sources`?

Comment: @DavidG - I could not get the exclusions to work otherwise, and noted the example given here was working.
https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/850#issuecomment-303870563